# How to get co-workers to put in fair contribution to project?

Tags: colleagues, collaboration, coworking

I work as a public school teacher. My principal requires all teachers to join one committee. Each committee has unique responsibilities, for instance, the "Party Planning Committee" plans staff parties. I was placed in charge of the "Yearbook Committee" which produces the yearbook.

Though four teachers joined my committee, only one contributed any work. The others ignored simple assignments and deadlines and contributed absolutely nothing.

Though I was officially placed in charge of the team, I am not aware of having actual authority over anyone. If no yearbook was produced, I would be blamed, and the co-workers joined my team knowing the work would get done whether they helped or not.

My principal offered me no suggestions when I mentioned the problem, just silence. She herself at another time mentioned similar struggles herself getting her staff to do their job.

In the coming year, how can I get co-workers to contribute to the project, despite my seeming lack of actual authority over them?

Comment: You have the same problem group projects in school cause.  I've never heard of someone solving it.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to get them to contribute?

Comment: @Kilisi I'm guessing because the OP is responsible for the project?

Comment: "My principal requires all teachers to join one committee." Are you guys getting paid for this work? If this is volunteer work, then, that's your problem right there. No one should be doing this work. Publish a blank yearbook. And have the people that really want their picture in there to do the work.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

You just experienced how students feel about *any* group project. They are forced into it, they cannot decide who to do it with and in the end they will be blamed for things totally outside of their control. Think about your own experience the next time you give out group projects as a teacher.

What can you do?

Well, you are in a unique position. Your output is a publication. You publish. And as the one actually *working* on the publication, you decide what is in it. The others don't, because they put no work in. So the easiest thing is to just not mention them at all. Your yearbook will (or should) have a page which says who contributed to the yearbook. So don't just say "The yearbook committee". List who did what. Matter of fact in many countries that is a legal requirement anyway for any publication. Those who contributed nothing, either leave them out, or put nothing next to their names. Or -depending on your style- make fun of them. If you make fun of people in the yearbook, you can as well continue making fun of your own team. You could list them as "Only helped themselves to cake" instead of "helped with photo editing" or "helped with printing house communications" that others have next to their names.

You cannot *make* someone work that you have zero authority over. But you don't have to give them credit for the work either. Just make sure you stick to the truth in who did what and you are good. If you want some of those that would be skipping assignments instead doing a really bad token job, you could announce your system of giving credit beforehand. But you really don't want that. Better work with a few dedicated people on a good product, than having to clean up the mess all the people make that don't want to be there anyway, but somehow feel forced to do anyway.

<sup>Sidenote: in my country, the *students* do the yearbook, with no teachers involved at all. The fact that nodoby has any authority over anybody else is very obvious from the start. Giving credit doesn't make anybody work harder, but it makes those who do have something to show for and those who just coast along or are no-shows basically had a zero sum game: they did not contribute to a voluntary activity and got not result from it either.</sup>

Comment: I like the points about group projects, but mocking the teachers in print sounds like a bad idea and bad example.  Just leave them out.

Comment: Well, again, it's a question of style. If you make fun of everyone, don't leave them out. If you don't, don't start with them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, one simple solution would be to suggest to the principal to rotate the team lead role of the yearbook committee.

For example, this year, you are the team lead, and some other team members don't really care to contribute because you will get blamed if the project fails and you will have to be the primary contributor.

Next year, someone else will be the team lead, and that person will have to be the primary contributor. You still can work hard to help that person in your supporting role if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

When you allow yourself to be put in charge of a project like this it usually means you've volunteered to do it all yourself. Any assistance you do get is just a bonus and usually comes through people either genuinely interested in the project or genuinely want to help you.

Most other people are just ticking boxes.

> In the coming year, how can I get co-workers to contribute to the project

Same way you get people to do anything. Give them some incentive.

Comment: It's not unusual at all in some workplaces to be volunteered for certain tasks.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie yeah, particularly with teachers. They volunteer you then it's sink or swim on your own.